# Keep the title in the first column instead of above both

Tags: titles, two-column

I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum, parskip}
\geometry{a4paper, twoside, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, marginparwidth=1.2cm, marginparsep=3mm, top=1cm, bottom=2cm}
\begin{document}
\title{Title\\
\large subtitle}
\date{2021}
\author{Author name}
\maketitle

\centering
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

which correctly renders to this:[image: rendered LaTeX]
However I'd like the title to be rendered above the first column only instead of above both, so that the second column may use the space that it would free. What would be a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can patch `\maketitle` to do `\@maketitle` instead of

```
\twocolumn[\@maketitle]
```

but you also probably want that the title starts at the same level as the second column. So you also need to patch `\@maketitle`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  left=1.5cm,
  right=1.5cm,
  top=1cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  marginparwidth=1.2cm,
  marginparsep=3mm,
}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
 {\twocolumn[\@maketitle]}
 {\@maketitle}
 {}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
 {\null\vskip2em}
 {\hrule height0pt\vspace{-2\topsep}\vspace{-2\parskip}}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title\\\large subtitle}
\date{2021}
\author{Author name}

\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `\maketitle` but rather set the title(s) manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum, parskip}
\geometry{
  paper=a4paper,
  twoside,
  hmargin=1.5cm,
  marginparwidth=1.2cm,
  marginparsep=3mm,
  top=1cm,
  bottom=2cm
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \LARGE % Title font size
  Title \par
  \large % Subtitle font size
  subtitle
  
  \vspace{1.5em}% Space between title and author
  
  \large % Author font size
  Author name
  
  \vspace{1em}% Space between author and date
  
  \large % Date font size
  \today
\end{center}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

In the above document the `center` environment is used to set the title components, taken directly from `\@maketitle` regarding the formatting and spacing. Of course, you can adjust it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the code for printing the title (`\@maketitle` in the `article` class code).

```
% twocolprob.tex  SE 608946

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum, parskip}
\geometry{a4paper, twoside, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, marginparwidth=1.2cm, marginparsep=3mm, top=1cm, bottom=2cm}

%%%%% just print the title
\makeatletter
\let\onecolmaketitle\@maketitle
\makeatother
%%%%%
\begin{document}
\title{Title\\
\large subtitle}
\date{2021}
\author{Author name}
\onecolmaketitle
\centering  %%% to me this gives a strange look
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]